# Python - Count duplicate words from a string of text and output each word with its number of occurences

Tags: python, excel, count, frequency

I have a words.txt file that contains a lot of duplicate words.

I want to sort the list and count the frequency with which each word appears.

I can theoretically do this by sorting and using COUNTIF in Excel, but I have a large file with >10K rows, so it's not practical to use Excel.

What I've done so far in a count.py file which I run by typing `python count.py words.txt`:

```
import re
from sys import argv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

script, filename = argv

cnt = Counter()

txt = open(filename).read()

freqword = defaultdict(list)
for word, freq in Counter(txt).items():
    freqword[freq].append(word)

for freq in sorted(freqword):
 print('count {}: {}'.format(freq, sorted(freqword[freq])))
```

However, this is returning to me a counts for each character when I want teach word. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: THanks to mhlester for pointing out that I needed to split txt into words by doing txt.split().

Here's my updated code:

```
from sys import argv
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename).read()
cnt = Counter(txt.split())
freqword = defaultdict(list)

for word, freq in cnt.items():
    freqword[freq].append(word)

for freq in sorted(freqword):
    print('count {}: {}'.format(freq, sorted(freqword[freq])))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line:

```
txt = open(filename).read()
```

`txt` is one string. So

```
Counter(txt)
```

Counts each character of the string.

In order to count each *word* of the string, you need to split it into words before the `Counter`:

```
Counter(txt.split())
```

Where no arguments passed to split uses all whitespace

Comment: Ah, just beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll edit my post to reflect the solution.

Comment: Why, @LNA? The question is the question, and the answer is the answer

Comment: I had some small issues in my original post -- e.g. I didn't use the cnt variable, and import re was extraneous. Just posting again because I wanted to fix it.

Comment: @LNA: if there are unrelated problems with your original post, it's fine to simplify that, preserving the core of the question.  But modifying your *question* so that it contains an *answer* doesn't make sense.